# How to fix error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl, microsoft-edge, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a PHP and while the application works in Internet Explorer, within Edge, where I want to run this application, I get error `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add the entire message/verbose log file content, as that could occur due to a variety of reasons, as well as the certificate details from `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <certificate>` _(same for the CA/ICA if not using a public CA/ICA)_, and the config file that references the certificate. The errors themselves are self-explanatory, but to troubleshoot requires the aforementioned data, as SSL version mismatch means there's a mismatch in the SSL/TLS version for the cert and config, Cipher Mismatch  means there's an SSL/TLS cipher mismatch, and CA invalid means the CA cert is invalid.

Comment: it sounds like your server is using an outdated and disabled type of SSL/TLS and/or an outdated set of available ciphers. for instance a modern browser will not support SSLv2/3 (or in some cases the newer TLS1.0/1.1) so if that is all the server has available, you'll get this message. another cause might be very old weak cryptographic primitives like 3DES, RSAv4, SHA1, etc that are no longer allowed. you can go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and point it at your server to determine what your current HTTPS settings are.

Comment: @Op, you mention different errors in your title vs your question. is your error  ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH, or both?

Comment: I get the error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH when I run the application on chrome & EDGE

Comment: @mouradsemi In order to determine the issue, the information requested in my prior comment is required.